# Refresh value in <div> in jsp file taken from java class

Tags: java, jsp

I'm newbie in java and jsp files. I have an application which is using java class to periodically download data from device and send it to the  in jsp file:

```
<div id="showtime">
            <%
                out.print(download.show[0]); <---- this is public table in java class download
            %>
</div>
```

Here is my question: is there any method I can use to refresh value in  taken from java class without refreshing whole page or reseting session timeout countdown?

Edit: I've tried some solutions with AJAX but it doesn't work, I don't know where I made mistake:

```
<script>
        function dateup(){
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/update",
                success: function(response){
                    $('#showtime').html(response);
                    alert("success");
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert("not success");
                }
            });
        }
</script>
```

Servlet update:

```
@WebServlet(name = "update")
public class update extends HttpServlet {


    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        String text = "some text";

        response.setContentType("text/plain");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        response.getWriter().write(text);.

    }

}
```

Mapping:

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>update</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>servlets.update</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>update</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/update</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And I changed `<div>` to:
`<div id="showtime"></div>`

Button to trigger function:
`<button onclick="dateup()">press here</button>`

But it doesn't work.  won't change it's context. This not trigger success function nor error one.

Comment: You'd probably need to do this via AJAX on the client side.

Comment: Adding on to @FedericoklezCulloca -  if so, you might want to take a look into Google Web Toolkit.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca It won't reset the session timeout countdown?

Comment: @mckdi What is "it" and what "session timeout countdown" are you talking about?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca By "it" I mean using ajax and by session timeout I mean Max Inactive Interval which is set after user had logged in.

Comment: Depending on how you handle your sessions, yes it may.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I made some edits.

Comment: Check your browser console is there any error showing ?

Comment: @Swati Shows nothing

Comment: Go to network tab of browser and see if request is make successfull or not .. Also , if status is `200`

Answer (score 1):

"JSP is a server side technology, which means that if you want to refresh the page you will have to perform a request to the server which will return the new page. It is not possible to just return part of a page through normal JSP mechanisms.

If you want to just refresh a value you will need to use javascript to make an ajax call to the server to get the data you need, and repopulate the value with this data."